# How to get URL of actual JavaScript document grabbed with $.get()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

If I use the `$.get()` method with JavaScript to grab an external file, if the url that I pass to the `$.get()` method is a php forwarder to the actual URL page, how can I get the URL of that second page?

```
...
  $.get("http://www.example.com/forwarder.php",
    function(response) {
...
```

So, how can I get the URL of the document that `response` relates to?

Comment: You mean, the resource that `$.get()` receives is at a different URL than the one used to request it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PHP page that is being requested sends a redirect header, then likely there is nothing you can do with jQuery to accomplish this.  The browser's internal mechanics handle redirects, and jQuery would be none the wiser.

You could always have the resultant page include its URI in the response, if it is in XML or JSON format.